# Facebook page - how can i get all albums using javascript sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the facebook page and all photos and albums are public.

I've used previously this query for get all albums:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/67695062976/albums
```

Now this query writes this error:

```
An access token is required to request this resource.
```

My javascript function for get all albums:

```
getAlbums: function()
    {

        $.get('http://graph.facebook.com/67695062976/albums?callback=?', {

            }, function (res) {
                $('#AlbumsContent').html("");


                $.each(res.data, function (key, value) {
                    var image = res.data[key];

                        $('#AlbumsContent').append('<div class="PhotosAlbums"><a id="buttonPhotosAlbums'+image.id+'" href="album-'+image.id+'"></a><div class="PhotosAlbumsName">'+image.name+'</div></div>');
                });



            }, "json");


    },
```

How can i fix this problem in javascript side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an Access Token for almost everything now, for public stuff of pages you can just use an App Access Token, which is the App Id and The App Secret, combined with a pipe:

> App-ID|App-Secret

There you go:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/67695062976/albums?access_token=App-ID|App-Secret
```

If you did not create an App yet, this is where you do it: https://developers.facebook.com/apps